# Why can't I get the height of a BST in one statement (Java)

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I was learning about binary search trees, and a practice problem involved recursively finding the height of the tree.

This is the Java code that was accepted:

```
public static int getHeight(Node root){
        if (root == null)
            return -1;
        else {
            int leftHeight = getHeight(root.left);
            int rightHeight = getHeight(root.right);

            if (leftHeight > rightHeight)
                return leftHeight + 1;
            else
                return rightHeight + 1;
        }
}
```

And this was the code (given as pseudocode in the tutorial) I tried at first and thought would work:

```
public static int getHeight(Node root){
     return 1 + Math.max(getHeight(root.left), getHeight(root.right));
}
```

However when I went to submit the second statement, it gave me a runtime error and NPEs. Is the `if (root == null){return -1};` a base case that the second statement doesn't implicitly have?

Comment: Yes. Any recursive function must have a path where it does not call itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when `root` is null then `root.left` is called that's why you are getting NPE.

And recursive function needs a base case which not called the recursive function again. Here, when `root` is `null` that means you are calling `getHeight()` on `root.left` or `root.right` where `root` is leaves of the tree that is the base case.

Answer (score 0):

@Eklavya has the right answer here, but since you're learning and I love recursion a couple good rules of thumb to add.

- Always have a termination condition in your code explicitly. Making termination implicit may be clever but communicating it and maintaining it are hard
- In Java, always assume a value is null in your method unless you have specifically annotated it otherwise. Unprotected child access is always a code smell
- Best practice in most languages with explicit privacy (like Java) is not to use members directly but to build an interface and reference methods from the interface (`root.left()` not `root.left`). It's a bit of pain now, but it will save you thousands of wasted hours if it's a habit you stay in.